# AmazonS3 PHP library not working behind squid

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3

What I have found till now is that:

proxy (squid) throws error code 417. This is due to HTTP/1.1 header "Expect: 100-continue" which squid does not handles properly

On Suppressing "Expect: 100-continue" header, curl returns incorrect header size

How do I proceed from here ?

Comment: If your proxy does not support the needed methods - the only things you can do is to change proxy to the one that can do that or set up NAT.

Comment: @zerkms: Can you please tell more about _NAT setup_?

Comment: try to google. It is a **lot** of articles there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Squid proxy MUST be used AND you cannot fix Squid, then you only have one solution: tunnel the API calls through to a server outside of your network and have that server forward the API calls to Amazon S3 on your behalf.

From a basic view you can just replicate all the S3 calls you use on your external server but you must be aware of the security implications, i.e. restricting the usage of the server to say the external IP address of your Squid server, or even API keys much like Amazon use themselves.

If more flexibility is available try another proxy preferably non-caching like [Pound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_%28networking%29).

Comment: It's very likely that the OP is inside of a corporate firewall, thus making the choice of a caching proxy intentional.  Nevertheless, this is a case of "then don't *do* that."

Comment: @Charles & @Steve-o: Yes my office has proxy server. I am supposed to work from behind Squid. Please suggest.

Comment: @Amit: updated answer, basically you are forced to proxy to an external server, and you have to implement that proxy protocol yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I really hate patronizing answers that indicate the person asking the question is an idiot. You see it all the time on this site and it's getting annoying.

for squid try this configuration directive:

```
ignore_expect_100 on
```