# S3ResponseError: 100 Continue - python (appengine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using boto python library (in appengine) for a couple of years in order to upload files to AWS S3.
With **no new changes** to the code I started getting the following error (on random occasions) when trying to change files on S3. The files are not updated after the error occurs.

My code is:

```
if website_bucket is not None:
    new_key = Key(website_bucket)
    new_key.key = "live/"+page_domain+"/"+s3_name
    new_key.set_metadata('original_filename', s3_name)
    if s3_name == "sitemap.xml":
        new_key.set_metadata('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
    else:
        new_key.set_metadata('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    new_key.set_contents_from_string(page_html, policy='public-read')
return s3_name
```

The error is:

```
in file /boto/s3/key.py", line 684, in sender
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 100 Continue
```

I don't know the version of the boto library...

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415849/amazons3-php-library-not-working-behind-squid

Comment: It was probably a communication error somewhere along the way (s3/appengine/dns).
The error disappeared the next day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happened again...

The boto version is 2.5.2

The fix is to comment the line:

```
headers['Expect'] = '100-Continue'
```

in the boto key.py file

Source:
https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fsminteractive%2Fboto%2Fcommit%2F59b0d6645db736138d87cf47a4c9e49d2a49e01e&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEJb1UtdqOlhjmQ-NthWZplGOB7oA

Comment: It also happened to me with boto 2.38.0. Aren't they going to release boto with this bug fixed? Are they aware of this bug?